# How to create global constant variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, constants

```
## My try to create a global constant 
Set-Variable -Name c -Value "x" -Option Constant -Scope Global -Force

Write-Host $c  ## -> x
$c = "y"       ## -> WriteError: (C:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException 
               ## -> VariableNotWritable
Write-Host $c  ## -> x

function test {
    Write-Host $c  ## -> x
    $c = "xxxx"
    Write-Host $c  ## -> xxxx
}

test
```

My variable `$c` is global accessible, but not constant in all cases. Try to change the value inside the function `test()` and PowerShell allows a change of value.

Is there a way to create a true global constant variable?

**Background:**

I have a main script. The main script loads a few modules. Through all the modules and in the main script I need some fixed file and registry paths.
So I want to declare these paths as global constants.

Comment: The value of `$global:c` never changes - when you do `$c = "xxxx"` inside `test`, powershell creates a local copy of `$c` - add `Write-Host $c` after the call to `test` and you'll see

Comment: `-Option Constant, AllScope`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *global* variable `$c` remains constant, but with the assignment `$c = "xxxx"` another *local* variable `$c` is defined that takes the new value and masks the global variable in the local context.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> Set-Variable -Name c -Value "x" -Option Constant -Scope Global -Force
PS C:\> function test {
>>     Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Global
>>     Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Local
>>     $c = "xxxx"
>>     Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Global
>>     Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Local
>> }
>>
PS C:\> test

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              x
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'c'.
At line:3 char:5
+     Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Local
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:String) [Get-Variable], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetVariableCommand

c                              x
c                              xxxx
```

The first `Get-Variable -Name c -Scope Local` call fails, because there is no local variable `$c` defined yet.

The issue can be avoided by prefixing the variable/constant with the correct scope:

```
PS C:\> Set-Variable -Name c -Value "x" -Option Constant -Scope Global -Force
PS C:\> function test {
>>     $global:c
>>     $global:c = "xxxx"
>>     $global:c
>> }
>>
PS C:\> test
x
Cannot overwrite variable c because it is read-only or constant.
At line:3 char:5
+     $global:c = "xxxx"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (c:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable

x
```

or by defining the constant for all scopes:

```
PS C:\> Set-Variable -Name c -Value "x" -Option Constant, AllScope -Force
PS C:\> function test {
>>     $c
>>     $c = "xxxx"
>>     $c
>> }
>>
PS C:\> test
x
Cannot overwrite variable c because it is read-only or constant.
At line:3 char:5
+     $c = "xxxx"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (c:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableNotWritable

x
```

Answer (score 1):

For a complete answer:

```
#________________________________________________
# Example1, without prefix
#________________________________________________
$c="val1"

# Print output c variable
$c

function test
{
    $c="val2"
}

test

# Print output c variable (c not change)
$c

#________________________________________________

# Example2, with prefix global
#________________________________________________
$global:c="val1"

# Print output c variable
$global:c

function test2
{
    $global:c="val2"
}

test2

# Print output c variable (c change)
$global:c

#________________________________________________

# Example3, with prefix script
#________________________________________________
$script:c="val1"

# Print output c variable
$script:c

function test3
{
    $script:c="val2"
}

test3

# Print output c variable (c change)
$script:c

#________________________________________________

# Example 4, with get and set variable --> see answer of Ansgar Wiechers
#________________________________________________
```

NB: Difference of global and script is a scope question. For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1).